# Isn't the none the complement of all in dependent probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability

I am reading the following problem:

> There is a political discussion group consisting of $5$ democrats, $6$
> republicans, and $4$ independents. Suppose that two group members are
> randomly selected in succession to attend a political convention. Find
> the probability of selecting no Independents

My solution was:
Probability of both selected are independents = $$\frac{4}{15}\cdot \frac{3}{14} =\frac{4}{70}$$
Probability of selecting no independents = $1$ - Probability of both selected are independents = $$ 1 - \frac{4}{70} = \frac{66}{70}$$

According to the solution this is wrong but why? Isnt the select none the complement of select $2$ in a sequence?

**Update** I am interested in understanding the falacy I am doing in the logic

Comment: The complement of choosing $0$ Independents is choosing at least $1$ independent, bot choosing $2$ independents.

Comment: In any case, there is no advantage to working backwards in this case.  There are $11$ non-independents in the group of $15$, so the answer is $\frac {11}{15}\times \frac {10}{14}=\frac {11}{21}$.

Comment: @lulu: I am not sure if you mean "both" here `bot choosing 2 independents.`.   I didn't understand why the logic for the complement is wrong though. I'd rather understand the falacy

Comment: I think what I wrote was clear, was it not?  Let $A$ be the event "no independents are chosen".  Then $A^c$ is the event "at least one of the chosen people is  independent "  You appear to have thought that $A^c$ was the event "both of the people chosen are independents" but that was incorrect.

Comment: Note:  my first comment contained a typo. I wrote "bot" when I meant to write "not".

Comment: @lulu: ah so it the inverse of none is at least one? And the inverse of all is none? Would you mind posting an answer explaining the logic. For some reason for me the first thought was that the inverse of none is all e.g like when we say "all or nothing"

Comment: Well, that would be the case if the only two options were all or nothing.  That's not the case here.  Here, you might have chosen $2$ Independents, or $1$, or none.  The complement of an event must cover *all* the other possibilities, so if we exclude none, we are left with $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Just to draw cheap examples, say you are dealt a five card hand from an ordinary $52$ card deck.  Suppose $B$ is the event "you got no Aces".  You would not imagine that the complement, $B^c$ is "you got all four Aces!" would you?  Again, the complement would just be "you got at least one Ace."